# What is a good way to make screenshot tests with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright

What is the good way to make a screenshot test with [playwright](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.4.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pagescreenshotoptions)?

If I understand truly, I need to make screenshot, like below:

```
it('Some test', async () => {
    page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
}
```

But how I can to compare it with etalon screenshots?
If I missed something in the docs, lets me know, please

Comment: Are you trying to do regression tests comparing images?

Comment: Yes. I would like to get something like this as a result:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-image-snapshot
I think, it is possible, but I have know idea how I need to do that

Answer (score 6):

judging by the fact that the Playwright team started developing their own test runner which can compare screenshots:

[playwright-test#visual-comparisons](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-test#visual-comparisons)

```js
import { it, expect } from "@playwright/test";

it("compares page screenshot", async ({ page, browserName }) => {
  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com");
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot();
  expect(screenshot).toMatchSnapshot(`test-${browserName}.png`, { threshold: 0.2 });
});
```

they do not plan to add such functionality directly to the Playwright

Comment: I've had a good experience with playwright-test but for others please note "Playwright test runner is available in preview and minor breaking changes could happen". There's quite a lot of movement on the API and this can cause some maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright's `toHaveScreenshot` and `toMatchSnapshot` are great if you want to compare a current screenshot to a screenshot from a previous test run, but if you want to compare two screenshots that you have as Buffers in memory you can use the `getComparator` method that Playwright uses behind the scenes:

```
import { getComparator } from 'playwright-core/lib/utils';

await page.goto('my website here');
const beforeImage = await page.screenshot({
    path: `./screenshots/before.png`
});
//
// some state changes implemented here
//
const afterImage = await page.screenshot({
  path: `./screenshots/after.png`
});

const comparator = getComparator('image/png');
expect(comparator(beforeImage, afterImage)).toBeNull();
```

The advantage of using `getComparator` is that it fuzzy matches, and you can set the threshold of how many pixels are allowed to be different. If you just want to check that the PNGs are exactly identical, a dead simple method to check for equality between the two screenshots is:

> expect(Buffer.compare(beforeImage, afterImage)).toEqual(0)

Beware though - this simpler method is flakey and sensitive to a single pixel difference in rendering (such as if any animations/transitions are not completed or if there are differences in anti-aliasing).

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to set the threshold in getComparator ? :)