# Cucumber-js + playwright: receiving "Error: toMatchSnapshot() must be called during the test" error when using .toMatchSnapshot()

Tags: playwright, cucumberjs

I have a need to setup a visual regression framework playwright + cucumber-js.
I finally made it to work somehow, but I can't make it to match screenshots via Playwright.
When execution reaches the row:

```
    expect(await page.locator(`${element}`).screenshot({ path: `${process.env.SCREENSHOTS_FOLDER}/${name}.png` }))
        .toMatchSnapshot(`${name}.png`);
```

it all ends with the error:

```
Then screen matches the base image for 'FrontPage' page 'header' element
       Error: toMatchSnapshot() must be called during the test
```

Seems like Playwright is missing the 'test' context, but I'm using cucumber and gherkin notation.
Is there any good way to make it work somehow?

Comment: Hope you are importing expect from '@playwright/test'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189645/what-is-a-good-way-to-make-screenshot-tests-with-playwright

Comment: Yes, I'm importing { expect, Page } from '@playwright/test'.
But the error is saying there is no test context. Because I'm really using cucumber .feature files and not that code is not inside the 'test', it is in the screenshot helper, which I am calling in one of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems from https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15800, you need to run playwright test runner to be able to call toMatchSnapshot.
Currently there is an open feature request for cucumber runner in https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15275.